# Integration tests with asp.net core (test of controllers without the views)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, testing, xunit

I am trying to setup a test project to test my controllers with identity and the database without having to define the views.

I have a unit test project where I can test my controller by instanciating it, passing the dbContext to the constructor.

```cs
 public class EventControllerTests
    {
        private readonly IEventRepository _eventRepository;
        private readonly EventController _controller;
        private readonly AppDbContext dbContext;

        const string cn = "Data Source=(localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=EventDb;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False";

        public EventControllerTests()
        {

            var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<EVNTS.Web.Database.AppDbContext>()
                .UseSqlServer(cn).Options;
            dbContext = new EVNTS.Web.Database.AppDbContext(options);
            // Arrange
            _eventRepository = new EventRepository(dbContext);
            _controller = new EVNTS.Web.Controllers.EventController(_eventRepository);
        }

        [Fact]
        public void ActionIndexTest()
        {
            // Act
            var result = _controller.Index(1);

            // Assert
            var model = (Event)result.Model;
            Assert.Equal(1, model.Id);
        }
    }
```

I have an integration test project where I use a WebApplicationFactory

```
 public class BasicTests : IClassFixture<WebApplicationFactory<EVNTS.Startup>>
    {
        private readonly WebApplicationFactory<EVNTS.Startup> _factory;
        private readonly HttpClient _client;

        public BasicTests(WebApplicationFactory<EVNTS.Startup> factory)
        {
            _factory = factory;
            _client = _factory.CreateClient();
        }

        [Theory]
        [InlineData("/")]
        public async Task Get_EndpointsReturnSuccessAndCorrectContentType(string url)
        {

            // Act
            var response = await _client.GetAsync(url);

            // Assert
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode(); // Status Code 200-299
            Assert.Equal("text/html; charset=utf-8",
                response.Content.Headers.ContentType.ToString());
        }


        [Fact]

        public async Task TestUserRegistration()
        {
            var s = _factory.Services.GetRequiredService<EVNTS.Web.Repositories.IEventRepository>();
            var url = "/user/register";
            var inputModel = new EVNTS.Web.ViewModels.RegisterModel()
            {
                UserName = "eric",
                Password = "123456",
                ConfirmPassword = "123456"
            };
            var sObj = JsonSerializer.Serialize(inputModel);
            var content = new StringContent(sObj, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
            var response = await _client.PostAsync(url, content);
            var result = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }

    }
```

The problem is that with the second option, the views have to be created and I need to use a library like AngleSharp to test the results.

I would like something in between where I can call the contructor directly and test the result view but with the DI injecting the UserManager and the dbContext for me.

any ideas?

Cheers

Here is the controller:

```
public class UserController : Controller
    {
        private readonly UserManager<User> _userManager;
        public UserController(UserManager<User> userManager)
        {
            _userManager = userManager;
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Register([FromBody] RegisterModel model)
        {
            IdentityResult? result=null;

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(model.UserName);
                if (user == null)
                {
                    user = new User
                    {
                        Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
                        UserName = model.UserName,
                    };
                    result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
                }
            }
            return View(result);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, can you post the controller action that you are testing as well?

Comment: Which one do you want me to post?

Comment: The Registration action

Comment: done, I have posted the registration action

Comment: If i understood right, you wan't to test if 'return View(result);' returned proper html?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also find this usefull sometimes when you want to check the result of a controller in an integration test condition without checking the view.

You can use the dependency injection and create a scope from the `WebApplicationFactory`.

```
        using (var serviceScope = Factory.Services.CreateScope())
        {
            var sut= serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetService<YourController>();

        }
```

To make this work you have to call the method `AddControllersAsServices()` in `Startup.cs` to register the controller in the DI container

```
            services.AddControllersWithViews(options => { options.ConfigureMvcOptionsForPortalModule(); })
            .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_3_0)
            .AddControllersAsServices();//add controller in DI to access it in integration testing
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no in between. The first example is a unit test, while the second is an integration test. If you want to just look at the result object of the action, then you'd use the unit test methodology, and you'd need to mock out your dependencies. Otherwise, you'd use the integration test approach, and you have to deal with the actual simulated server response.

For what it's worth here, controller actions should be integration tested, since they are inherently dependent on a number of components coming together, so you should be following the second approach, parsing the HTML response, if necessary.

Comment: Sorry, but I would like to develop the backend before any html.
I would like to deliver to the front-end developer a system that works without the views. 
So none of these two test projects works for me

Comment: You don't seem to understand. You'd start by testing your service classes or similar with unit tests, making sure the core functionality works. Then, you'd do integration testing on the controllers that utilize this functionality, and mostly test the response codes: you get a 200 when you should, 404 when you should, etc. If you want, you can eventually add tests to ensure that the actual views are correct, but that's not even required, as it's generally better to roll that into UI tests, via Selenium or something.

Comment: Your controllers should be light on code, anyways. All they do is tie everything together, hence why they are integration tested.

Comment: the controller is just a proof of concept to setup a testing environment.

Comment: Ok, let's forget about testing the controllers.
How can I test the services without Mocking?
The main question is; how can I popuplate the DI with the services needed to test my service

Comment: You wouldn't. Again, what you're talking about is a unit test, now, and for that you would create mocks of your dependencies. Fetching the dependencies out of the service collection would turn your unit test into an integration test, as then, you're invoking multiple "units" of functionality. You're looking for a shortcut, but the service collection is not that. You can use a mocking framework like Moq, to make things easier, but you still need mocks.

Comment: For me @EricImhauser need is totally right, testing the app with real dependencies (no mocks) and without relying on view details, like html tags that are very fragile and not resistant to refactoring, is really a good option for integration testing. This is exactly the subject of Vladimir Khorikov's Unit testing book. [link](https://www.manning.com/books/unit-testing)

Answer (score 0):

I don't consider myself an authority on how to perform unit testing, but since the comment section is restricted in characters I will write my comments here.

Usually, when you find yourself in a situation where it's difficult to come up with a good unit test (I won't define "good" here) more often than not, it is because there are some problems with the project structure/code design, and not actual limitations of the unit testing itself (again, not that unit testing doesn't have it's limitations, but I think this is not the case here).

Based on the above I asked you to include the action's code so we can examine what exactly are you trying to test and why it is so hard.

Here comes the heavily opinion-based part of my comment, but I leave it up to you wether you would want to take some of this or leave it.

It's not a rule, but a good rule of thumb is that the controller should contain very little business logic, which means that unit testing a controller should be basically testing the different paths that the request could go, once it hits the controller.

Generally you would want something like this:

```
if (!ModelState.IsValid)
{
  return BadRequest(ModelState);
}

var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(model.UserName);
...
return View(result);
```

which then you can unit test with something like this:

```
public async Task Register_Returns_BadRequest_On_Invalid_Model()
{
  var testUsername = "TestUsername";
  var mockUserManager = new Mock<IUserManager>();
  mockUserManager.Setup(m => m.FindByNameAsync(testUsername))
    .Returns(Task.FromResult(**Not sure about this part**))
  var controller = new RegisterController(mockUserManager.Object);

  var result = await controller.Register(model: null);

  var actionResult = Assert.IsType<ActionResult<IdentityResult>>(result);
  Assert.IsType<BadRequestObjectResult>(actionResult.Result);
}
```

For the happy path you want only to check that on a valid ModelState the result is of type **ActionResult>**

What is my idea:

- When you unit test the controller you should not be bothered by the actual data, this is responsibility of other parts of the application
- The controller unit test should be plain simple, most of the time you should be testing only those two cases - invalid data returns some sort of BadRequest, valid data returns the expected response
- If you find yourself mocking too much objects most of the time it's a clear sign that you need some additional layer of abstraction.

In your case, in order to make my code better structured and easier for testing I would do the following:

- First test for invalid ModelState - you don't want to proceed if the ModelState is invalid and this should also be covered by an unit test.
- Managers should be a higher level of abstraction. Methods like **FindByNameAsync** and  **CreateAsync** are more suitable for the data access layer. In the case of this action, your `UserManager` can have a method like `Register` so your controller's action look like this:

  if (!ModelState.IsValid)

  {

  ```
  return BadRequest()
  ```

  }

  var result = _userManager.Register(model.UserName);

  return View(result);
- Now you can remove the Find and Create methods from the controller and create a `UserRepository` where I thin those methods belong and where you can test them in isolation.

In this setup You have these abstractions Controller -> Manager -> Repository. Now you try to test the three of these in one single method, which is causing the problems in my opinion.

Also, just because I find this a bit more tidy, usually you use a `Service` layer and if the structure is too complex you add the manager layer so it becomes Controller -> Manager -> Service -> Repository. In your case I'm not sure that you need this complexity so maybe just for the sake of better naming, rename the `UserManager` to `UserService`, so that your code flow is Controller -> Service -> Repository.

Also, last pease of advice. Controller testing has always been contraversial so don't be too bothered if you don't cover your controller with unit tests as much as other parts of the code. This is somewhat expected, what I wanted to tell with this post is mainly that the problem wasn't how to test but rather is the code testable as it is, which in my opinion could be improved as I've shown above. Yes, my proposition is not perfect as well but it creates smaller chunks of code which are encapsulated, don't have that many dependencies which ultimately makes them easier to test. And of course this is not a substitution of the integrations tests.

Hope this gave you some food for thought.

Comment: I appreciate the time spent on nswering to my question but this doens't give me any solution on how to develop the backend and test controllers and underlying services without having to develop the views. 
I posted the controller just for info and not tp be proofed; this is just a POC project to setup a testing environment that works.

Comment: @EricImhauser No problem. It was usfeful for me to write this anyway. I saw the discussion with Christ Pratt and there is not much to add. I think he has good points.